# PHP/ImageMagic Get the "shadow" of an image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I would like to script PHP/ImageMagic in order to produce the "shadow" of a given image. Like in this example (done manually in GFXeditor) :

```
      original                shadow
```

[alt text http://uppix.net/d/a/f/dc82fce795fc4af20170080b09c9a.png](http://uppix.net/d/a/f/dc82fce795fc4af20170080b09c9a.png) ==> [alt text http://uppix.net/8/9/9/b1e9df4b2858c40081771961e028d.png](http://uppix.net/8/9/9/b1e9df4b2858c40081771961e028d.png)

*Note: All the originals images will be on a white background like in the example.*

I've check the ImageMagic documentation but I haven't found anything useful yet. Does anyone know if it can be done in PHP/ImageMagic ? If so how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `convert` with [`-threshold`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#threshold) option?

EDIT: oops... from PHP?  `Imagick::thresholdImage`?

I wonder if it isn't more like a mask than a shadow? [In the context of IM](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/), *shadow* looks like a blurry copy of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [edge detection](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#edge) chapter in the ImageMagick examples.